# Why do the TextBlocks leak memory when running on .NET Framework 4 and Windows XP?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory-leaks, windows-xp

I have been trying to debug this leak for a while now and finally was able to break it down to a very simple example. First of all, I am developing a WPF application that still needs Windows XP support due to client request.

Based on my problem I have created a simple example which fills up my RAM on a Windows XP .NET Framework 4 machine. I do not have thoses problems on Windows 8 for example.

How it works: The main view (MainPage) displays a new instance of a view (DynamicPage) in the content section of a usercontrol (PageTransition) based on an interval. It's compareable to a slideshow behaviour but only with one slide for simplicity.

On the clients machine (Windows XP, .NET 4) the RAM of thoses TextBlock.Text objects will never be released. I won't experience a leak if I remove the Text property. Now I am wondering why this is happening? What am I missing here?

MainPage

```
<Window x:Class="PageRotationBug.View.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageRotationBug"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PageRotationBug.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <controls:PageTransition x:Name="PageControl" TransitionType="GrowAndFade"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage Code-Behind

```
public partial class MainPage : Window
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }


    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        PageControl.OpenPage(new DynamicPage());
    }

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
}
```

DynamicPage

```
<UserControl x:Class="PageRotationBug.View.DynamicPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageRotationBug.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="Purple">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="hello world 1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="hello world 2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="hello world 3"/>
    <TextBlock Text="hello world 4"/>
    <TextBlock Text="hello world 5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

PageTransition Control

```
public partial class PageTransition : UserControl
{
    public PageTransition()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OpenPage(UserControl page)
    {
        Pages.Push(page);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                if (ContentPresenter.Content != null && ContentPresenter.Content is UserControl)
                {
                    UserControl currentPage = ContentPresenter.Content as UserControl;
                    currentPage.Loaded -= NewPage_Loaded;

                    Storyboard hidePage = (Resources[string.Format("{0}Out", TransitionType.ToString())] as Storyboard);
                    hidePage.Completed += HidePage_Completed;
                    hidePage.Begin(ContentPresenter);
                    return;
                }
                ShowPage();
            });
        });
    }

    private void HidePage_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard hidePage = (Resources[string.Format("{0}Out", TransitionType.ToString())] as Storyboard);
        hidePage.Completed -= HidePage_Completed;
        GC.Collect();
        ShowPage();
    }

    private void ShowPage()
    {
        UserControl newPage = Pages.Pop();
        newPage.Loaded += NewPage_Loaded;
        ContentPresenter.Content = newPage;
    }

    private void NewPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard showNewPage = Resources[string.Format("{0}In", TransitionType.ToString())] as Storyboard;
        showNewPage.Begin(ContentPresenter);
        CurrentPage = sender as UserControl;
    }

    public UserControl CurrentPage { get; set; }

    Stack<UserControl> Pages = new Stack<UserControl>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TransitionTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TransitionType",
        typeof(PageTransitionType),
        typeof(PageTransition), new PropertyMetadata(PageTransitionType.GrowAndFade));

    public PageTransitionType TransitionType
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageTransitionType)GetValue(TransitionTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TransitionTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public enum PageTransitionType
{
    GrowAndFade
}
```

Comment: It's always difficult to diagnose memory leaks by only analyzing the source code. Have you tried to run a memory profiler on the target system to find out why the objects don't get GCed?

Comment: Yes I have tried to find the objects that do not get released using the .NET Memory Profiler on the WindowsXP Machine but I am not quite sure if I make the right interpretation. I made two snapshots and compared them but could not find any significant difference.